# Remove BOM from string with Perl

Tags: string, perl, text, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have the following problem: I am reading from a UTF-8 text file (and I am telling Perl that I am doing so by ":encoding(utf-8)").

The file looks like this in a hex viewer:
EF BB BF 43 6F 6E 66 65 72 65 6E 63 65

This translates to "∩╗┐Conference" when printed. I understand the "wide character" which I am being warned about is the BOM. I want to get rid of it (not because of the warning, but because it messes up a string comparison that I undertake later).

So I tried to remove it using the following code, but I fail miserably:

$line =~ s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//;

Can anyone enlighten me as to how to remove the UTF-8 BOM from a string which I obtained by reading the first line of the UTF-8 file?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you have the output encoding set correctly there should be no need to remove the BOM, because a zero-width space will have no effect on the result

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`EF BB BF` is the UTF-8 encoding of the BOM, but you decoded it, so you must look for its decoded form. The BOM is a ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (U+FEFF) used at the start of a file, so any of the following will do:

```
s/^\x{FEFF}//;
s/^\N{U+FEFF}//;
s/^\N{ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE}//;
s/^\N{BOM}//;   # Convenient alias
```

See also: [File::Bom](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::BOM).

---

> *I understand the "wide character" which I am being warned about is the BOM. I want to get rid of it*

You're getting wide character because you forgot to add an `:encoding` layer on your output file handle. The following adds `:encoding(UTF-8)` to STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR, and makes it the default for `open()`.

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Comment: to use the shorthand, I needed to add
 use charnames ':full';

Comment: I think 5.12 is needed for `\N{...}` I think 5.14 is needed for `\N{BOM}`. `use charnames ':full';` is needed before 5.16.

Comment: @user1769925: Note that the problem is that you have *decoded* the data from the file (because of your `:encoding(utf-8)` open mode) so the first *character* of the input string is Unicode `U+FEFF`, but you are using raw UTF-8-encoded data bytes in your substitution

Comment: These solutions caused compile time errors until I added this code: use charnames ":full";.  After that, the solutions still failed in making any change.  What ultimately solved this for me: use Encode; my $value = decode('UTF-8', $value); $value =~ s/\N{U+FEFF}//;

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, It was already mentioned that one needs `use charnames ":full";` in old versions of Perl. /// A crucial part of the question is the equivalent of `decode('UTF-8', $value)` had already been performed -- their code would have worked if they hadn't already decoded the text -- so adding `decode('UTF-8', $value)` would actually be wrong here.

Answer (score 6):

To defuse the BOM, you have to know it's not 3 characters, it's 1 in UTF (U+FEFF):

```
s/^\x{FEFF}//;
```

Comment: As @ikegami noted, decoding to UTF-8 is needed, i.e. `decode_utf8()`.

Answer (score 6):

If you open the file using [File::BOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBOM), it will remove the BOM for you.

```
use File::BOM;

open_bom(my $fh, $path, ':utf8')
```

Comment: not in the standard library

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your filehandle should be doing this for you automatically.  But if you're not in an ideal situation, this worked for me:

```
use Encode;

my $value = decode('UTF-8', $originalvalue);
$value =~ s/\N{U+FEFF}//;
```

Comment: There is `decode_utf8()` shortcut.