# Remove UTF-16 BOM from string with Perl

Tags: perl, unicode, character-encoding, utf-16, byte-order-mark

I'm looking for the correct syntax to remove the BOM from a UTF-16 text file  I have successfully done it for UTF-8.  Please see below for syntax I have tried:

```
$readline =~ s/^\N{ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE}//;
$readline =~ s/^\N{BYTE ORDER MARK}//;
$readline =~ s/^\N{BOM}//;
$readline =~ s/^\x{FEFF}//;
$readline =~ s/^\0x{FEFF}//;
$readline =~ s/^\x{FE}\x{FF}//;
$readline =~ s/^\xFE\xFF//;
$readline =~ s/^\0xFE\0xFF//;
```

As you can see these are repetitive but I was trying anything I could find.  To open the file I used the encoding function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove BOM from string with Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390034/remove-bom-from-string-with-perl)

Comment: Also http://www.larshaendler.com/2014/03/14/remove-bom-while-reading-file-with-perl/

Comment: @DavidO, That removes the UTF-8 encoding of the BOM.

Comment: This cannot be answered unless you tell us whether you have bytes or characters first.

Answer (score 5):

What's in `$readline`?

If you have UTF-16be,

```
s/^\xFE\xFF//
```

If you have UTF-16le,

```
s/^\xFF\xFE//
```

If you have Unicode Code Points (decoded text),

```
s/^\x{FEFF}//
s/^\N{BOM}//
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use [File::BOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::BOM) to both remove the mark and decode the stream.

Comment: +1, though if I may be a bit pedantic, I think that "UTF-16BE" and "UTF-16LE" are really supposed to refer to the two versions of UTF-16 that do *not* allow a byte order mark. The UTF-16 that *does* allow a BOM, and can therefore have either endianness (defaulting to BE if there's no BOM), is supposed to be called just "UTF-16". (See http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#gen7.)

Comment: I agree that "UTF-16 that's encoded in little-endian byte order" is too long-winded, but I don't know why you suggest that as the alternative. What's wrong with "little-endian UTF-16"?

Comment: Actually, nothing in the passage you linked says that UTF-16le and UTF-16be can't have a BOM. (It just says that UTF-16 may have one.)

Comment: Right, because that's just a convenient FAQ, not a formal spec. For the latter, see [RFC 2781](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2781), which specifies that "Systems labelling UTF-16BE text MUST NOT prepend a BOM to the text" and so on.

Comment: That passage explains what it means when an application says it expects "UTF-16le" or "UTF-16be". It's not relevant here. Read on to 4.1. A BOM can still lead UTF-16le and UTF-16be. It just doesn't effect how the stream is processed.

Comment: In other words, if I say I require UTF-16le, and you produce something starting with `FE FF`, it's still going to be treated as UTF-16le. The usage in my answer is therefore in line with the RFC. It's technically the OP in error by calling it a BOM instead of a ZWNBS

Comment: I think you have that backward. It's generally the producer, not the consumer, that specifies the character-set (e.g. as part of an HTTP `Content-Type` header). So if I send a document marked as `UTF16-LE` or `UTF-16BE`, then the RFC is saying that I *must not* include a BOM.

Comment: Makes no diff. Like I said, if it's not a BOM, then it's a ZWNBS, and the answer remains the same.

Comment: But then how did you decide that it's not a BOM? Nothing in the original question suggests that the OP is using "UTF-16BE" or "UTF-16LE".

Comment: @ruakh, The question isn't encoding detection. The OP didn't ask to detect if they have UTF-16le + BOM or UTF-16be + BOM, so they must therefore know which one they have. In fact, the OP tagged the question UTF-16le (subsequently removed by tchrist). If they need BOM-based encoding detection, they should use File::BOM as I mentioned, or just `open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-16)', ...)`

Comment: Ah, OK. Fair enough.